# Add Test-Assets for XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, testing, xctest

I want to do a couple of tests regarding images (e.g. if image are resized correctly).

How can I add specific images (or assets) to a project that are only available for the tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your images or assets to your project then set the "Target Membership" for your test target in the "File Inspector".

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris, this seems like the right approach. However, when I try `let testImg = UIImage.init(named: "IMG_4840-1")
        print(testImg?.size)` I get `nil`, so the image cannot be loaded. Do you know why?

Comment: It's because you have to specify test bundle probably. Try `let bundle = Bundle(for: YourTestClass.self)` and then use `init?(named name: String, inBundle bundle: NSBundle?, compatibleWithTraitCollection traitCollection: UITraitCollection?)` initializer for UIImage.